# How to GetXpathCount of all rows and columns in a table that doesn't have an id?

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium

/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/font/a

/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[4]/font/a

/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[2]/font/a

/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[4]/font/a

/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[2]/font/a

/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[4]/font/a

```
int count = (int)Selenium.GetXpathCount("/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/");
```

Comment: What value are you getting now?

Comment: You' get better answers if you include a sample source document and exact desired output for that input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `selenium.getXpathCount("xpath=/html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/")`

or

```
selenium.getXpathCount("//html/body/table/tbody/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use "class" name of the table and you will get it for sure.
It's like this:

```
int rowCount = Selenium.getXpathCount("//table[@class='<Class Name of the Table>]/tbody/tr").intValue();
```